# Zeros at all even places in the binary expansion

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the set of numbers in $[0,1]$ whose binary expansion has $0$ in all even places is a set of measure $0$.

$x\in [0,1]$ in binary expansion can be written as $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n \frac{1}{2^n}$ where $\alpha_n \in \{0,1\}$. In our case we have $\alpha_{2n}=0$ so
$$x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_{2n+1} \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}$$

How can we show that this set is countable (and hence has measure $0$). Or it is not?

Comment: It is uncountable.

Comment: It does have measure $0$, though.

Answer (score 0):

The set of odd places is countably infinite, sometimes denoted $\aleph_0$. You may choose each odd place to be either $0$ or $1$, and correspondingly the cardinality of these numbers is $2^{\aleph_0}$, which is uncountable.

Comment: Thank you. But still how can we show that the set has measure $0$?

Comment: @user16015 you can show it directly. For instance, removing the terms with $a_2 = 1$ amounts to removing some intervals of length $1/2$. Removing terms with $a_4 = 1$ from the leftover amounts to removing intervals of length $1/2^2$, and so on.